# DataGridView Copy Paste differentiate between blank cells and skipped cells?

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy, copy-paste, paste

I have implemented a C# DataGridView and built copy/paste functionality as has been described in other posts:

```
        // Copy Code
        DataObject d = ws.GetClipboardContent();
        if (d != null)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
        }
```

//

```
        // Paste Code
        string s = Clipboard.GetText();
        string sWithoutSlashR = s.Replace("\r", "");    // get rid of \r if it exists
        string[] lines = sWithoutSlashR.Split('\n');
        int row = ws.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        Boolean allGood = true;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            int col = ws.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            string[] cells = line.Split('\t');
            int cellsSelected = cells.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < cellsSelected; i++)
            {
                if (col < ws.ColumnCount && row < ws.RowCount)
                {
                    ws.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = cells[i].ToString();
                }
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
```

A problem arises if the copy source cells have a blank in them and the paste destination cells are not empty.  Imagine three cells are being copied that have contents "T", "", "T" (i.e. quotes are just for your readability - the middle cell is blank).  If the user selects all three cells then what gets copied is: "T\r\n\r\nT".  Pasting this overwrites the middle cell with a blank which is fine.

However, if the user selects only the first and third cell with the control key, then what gets copied is the same thing:  "T\r\n\r\nT".  Since the user didn't select the empty middle cell, the empty middle cell shouldn't be pasted, but it does!

How do I differentiate between a selected empty cell vs a skipped cell since the copy contents are the same?

Mike

Comment: I have to ask why you are using the OS Clipboard for this? From what I can tell, the OS COPY is going to add “empty” values for each non-selected cell between the two cells. I am wondering why you don’t use the “grids” `SelectedCells` collection to copy and paste. The `SelectedCells` collection will only contain the “selected” cells and each cell will have a row/column property. Is there some reason you must use the OS COPY for this?

Comment: Once user has completed the copy operation and moved to a new cell for the paste operation, the SelectedCells no longer represents the copy source.  Other posts suggested using OS Clipboard to provide flexibility for user to paste to other locations within DataGridView or ability to paste to other applications such as Excel.

Comment: Your comment… _”Once user has completed the copy operation and moved to a new cell for the paste operation, the SelectedCells no longer represents the copy source.”_ … create a global var `LastSelectedCells`… then, when the user clicks the COPY button, simply set `LastSelectedCells` to a new copy of the grids currently selected cells collection. Then when the user clicks the paste… it can use the `LastSelectedCells` collection.

Comment: I thought DataGridViewCellCollection only supported one dimensional arrays.  Can DataGridViewCellCollection support two dimensional array of selected cells (i.e. cells arranged in rows and columns)?

Comment: As I said earlier... Each cell in the collection has a row and column property.

Comment: Hmmm... Struggling with syntax of copying selected cells to DataGridViewCollection.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It works fine. If you want to skip the `null` value cells, do that in the inner loop.

Comment: @JQSOFT - Two different user sequences result in same data stored in OS Clipboard.  Copying a blank cell or user using CTRL key to skip selecting the blank cell result in same text.  Since the text is the same, I don't know if I should skip pasting the blanks.  If they copied blank cell, then I want to paste.  If they used CTRL key to skip selecting the blank cell, then I don't want to paste.  Only an issue when pasting to cells that already have content, but it is annoying.

Comment: Also, either the user selects adjacent cells or separated ones using the `Ctrl` key, what copied is a _selection range_ regardless of the values. Nothing skipped.

Comment: @JQSOFT … what if a “selected” cell was empty and you did NOT want to “ignore” it? Point being, that using the OS’s copy… it is impossible to distinguish a non-selected cell from an “empty selected” cell.

Comment: Definition… `DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection nonSortedSelectedCells;` … In the copy code: … `nonSortedSelectedCells = ws.SelectedCells;` .You need to bear in mind that the grids `SelectedCells` collection takes into account WHICH cell was selected “first” (the last item in the collection) and “last” (the first item in the collection). This mean that the order by which the user “selects” the cells will determine the order in the array.

Comment: The OS’s copy will NOT have info about the selection order nor care about the order. It will start at the top and work to the bottom. Therefore, to get the “selected” cells into a “top-down” fashion regardless of the order selected as the OS’s copy does… you should “sort” the collection based on the row index of each cell.

Comment: @JohnG It will be pasted in the same order buddy. No need for the `SelectedCells`. The `GetClipboardContent()` does the necessary to describe the copied range. From where it starts and to where it ends. In the same order.

Comment: @JQSOFT … I am not sure if I understand, are you saying the you want to “ignore” the empty values in the paste? As my understanding is that the empty values are overwriting current values when they should not.

Comment: @JohnG No, Just if you need to do that. Otherwise the paste should overwrite the same copied range. It works the same way in Excel Sheet. What do you get when you copy and paste a _Range_? Excel doesn't understand what in your mind, it overwrites the same range starting from the selected cell. If you want to do special pastes, then you have to Macro. Likewise here, If you need a special paste, tell how through the code.

Comment: @JQSOFT ... I am confused… you commented… _”Otherwise the paste should overwrite the same copied range.”_ … yes it will AND this IS what is happening and from my understanding (I guess I may be wrong) the OP’s question is to NOT overwrite those cells where the (non-selected cell) copied value is “empty”…My understanding is that the cells that were NOT selected, when pasted, are overwriting cells that contain data with these non-selected cells. The OP does NOT want this… I guess I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnG - Thanks for the clarification.  Using the type DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection instead of DataGridViewCellCollection did the trick. If you want to write this up as an Answer, I will be happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: @JQSOFT-Issue is that when non-continuous cells are selected using the mouse and CTRL key, unselected middle cells within range ARE included in the OS clipboard text. I could skip these cells when pasting, but if I did, then when user selects an empty cell in the middle that would be skipped as well. In my application, if user pastes blank cell, user expects the blank to overwrite value in destination cell. Using DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection to store copied data instead of OS clipboard better represents user's intention when copying. Empty cells are copied, but skipped middle cells not.

Comment: I must admit, that in my previous attempts at doing a copy/paste in the same grid or to another grid… it became apparent that it is more complex that meets the eye. For starters, as it appears you have noted already is “what to do if the selected cells and the starting position where you want to paste the cells… runs OFF the grid?” Your current code appears to simply “ignore” those cells that “run” off the grid with the line… `if (CurPasteCol < ws.ColumnCount && CurPasteRow < ws.RowCount) {` … this works, however there is another possible problem here.

Comment: This same problem will still exist if you use the OS’s copy. If ALL the cells in the grid are of type “Text”, then it should work. However, if the columns are of “different” types… like one column being an `int` type column… then, if the code tries to “paste” a non-numeric string value into that column… then you will get the grids dreaded `DataError.` Therefore, if you have different column types… you will need to check this before pasting to avoid the error. If you want an example with ALL string columns, then let me know and I will post one. Otherwise, you can post your own answer.

Comment: In my particular application, all cells are text strings, so i think it will work.  Will take a day or so to build it out, but I am hopeful using DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection will work.

Answer (score 1):

Shout out to JohnG for getting me in the right direction!  Here is my solution:

Global variable:

```
DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection copySource;
```

My DataGridView is named ws in sample below.  Within copy command accessed by CTRL+C or context menu, I populate the global variable:

```
copySource = ws.SelectedCells;
```

Paste command is as follows:

```
        if (copySource == null) return;     // nothing to paste, so leave 
        if (copySource.Count == 0) return;  // nothing to paste, so leave

        // find top left Source cell
        int topSourceRow = copySource[0].RowIndex;
        int leftSourceCol = copySource[0].ColumnIndex;
        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in copySource)
        {
            if (cell.RowIndex < topSourceRow) topSourceRow = cell.RowIndex;
            if (cell.ColumnIndex < leftSourceCol) leftSourceCol = cell.ColumnIndex;
        }

        // find top left destination cell
        int topDestRow = ws.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        int leftDestCol = ws.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;

        // paste cells
        Boolean allGood = true;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in copySource)
        {
            // check if we have run off the edge of the grid
            // todo: expand if statement to add type checks if needed
            if (topDestRow + cell.RowIndex - topSourceRow >= ws.Rows.Count || leftDestCol + cell.ColumnIndex - leftSourceCol >= ws.Columns.Count)
            {
                // do not paste, set flag to show warning
                allGood = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // perform paste
                ws.Rows[topDestRow + cell.RowIndex - topSourceRow].Cells[leftDestCol + cell.ColumnIndex - leftSourceCol].Value = cell.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        if (!allGood)
        {
            // todo: display warning to user that not all cells were pasted
        }
```

Initial smoke tests show that blank cells are copied and overwrite the destination cells properly.  Copying discontinuous cells behaves as expected - skipped cells in the middle of the copy source are not included in paste.

The assumption built into this approach is that the user has selected the upper left corner of the destination cells for pasting which I think is reasonable.

If the paste goes off the right or bottom edge, cells that can be pasted are pasted.  Cells off the edge are skipped and a warning message is displayed to the user.  Your error checking requirements may vary.

In my application, I am going to keep my original code to copy source cells to the OS Clipboard to give users flexibility to copy from my application to Excel or other destinations.

Answer (score 0):

After the lengthy discussion, I wanted to clarify some things. My solution below is very similar to Mike Paisner answer and I give him a thumbs up on finding working a solution. Well done… upvote from me.

In reference to using the OS’s copy command, it will work depending on what you want. In Mike Paisner’s original question, the code uses the OS’s copy command to copy the “selected” cells in the grid. When using the OS’s copy command, the paste was overwriting cells that were NOT selected with “empty” values.

This is true given how the OS structures a copy command with cells selected in a `DataGridView`. Using the posted code in the original post, it works as described above, overwriting non-selected cells with empty values. If you wanted to “ignore” the empty values and NOT overwrite those cells, then a simple check in the original code should fix this issue. Something like…

```
if (col < ws.ColumnCount && row < ws.RowCount) {
  if (cells[i].ToString() != "") {   // <-- added check for empty (non-selected) cells
    ws.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = cells[i].ToString();
  }
  else {
     // empty cell value
   }
}
```

This works and will stop overwriting cells that were not selected. However, as mention previously, IF the user selected an “empty” cell and then clicked the copy button, selected another cell, and then clicked the paste button, whatever value was in the cell to be pasted into would remain unchanged. If this is the desired behavior, then the code is done, however, IMHO, if I selected an empty cell and copy pasted it, then it should NOT ignore the pasted value simply because it is an empty value.

IF you wanted to copy the empty cells when they are selected, then using the OS’s copy command WILL NOT WORK. It will be difficult to distinguish empty “selected” cells from “NON-selected” cells. Please understand, I do not want to dissuade anyone from using the OS’s copy command, in many cases it is the best approach. However, in the OPs case, this will not work since they want to be able to paste “empty” cells.

Given this, my suggestion is to use the `DataGridView`’s `SelectedCells` collection to manage the paste process. Using this collection requires a different approach and a little more work. For starters, as noted in the comments, is that when the user selects the cell to paste into, then the `SelectedCells` collection will start over with the selected cell we want to paste into. Thus, removing the previously selected cells we need. I suggest a global variable to store the selected cells when the copy button is clicked. Then when the paste button is clicked, we can use the global variable that holds the previously selected cells.

The `SelectedCells` collection is a single dimension “dynamic” array and obviously grows/shrinks when cells are selected/deselected. Technically, the collection is a “Stack”’ or FIFO (first in first out) … the “first” cell in the collection was the “last” cell selected and the “last” cell in the collection was the “first” cell selected. This obviously gives you the ability to know the order the cells were selected. This is by design and makes sense, however for this case it is irrelevant what order the cells were selected. Same as the OS copy, we are only concerned with the position of the “top-left” cell of the rectangle created by the selected cells.

Because the cells are ordered in the same order the user selected the cells, we need to find the “top-left” cell of the rectangular selection (light green cell R1C1). Example; Using the picture below, the selection was made using the Ctrl key to multi-select the cells in this order, col2, col1, col4 and col3.

[image]

The selected cells array would look like…

```
Index   cellValue
  0       R3C3
  1       R1C4
  2       R3C1
  3       R5C2
```

In this example, we want to find the “lowest” numbered column and row in the collection. We can loop through the collection or, since the collection is enumerable, we could simply sort the collection based on the column index then grab the first items column index. Then sort it by row index and grab the first items row index. It may look like…

```
int colIndex = copyCollection.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(c => c.ColumnIndex).First().ColumnIndex;
int rowIndex = copyCollection.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(c => c.RowIndex).First().RowIndex;
```

This will give us the top-left cell (light green cell) from the selection rectangle (pink rectangle in the picture). In this example, the first column would be column 1 and the top row would be row 1. Let us say the user clicked on the “R5C0” cell (dark green) to paste.

Now we want to get the “magic” numbers we need to add to each selected cell’s row and column index. Looking at the picture this difference would be the difference between the two green cells. This may look like…

```
int colDif = ws.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex - colIndex
int rowDif = ws.CurrentCell.RowIndex - rowIndex;
```

Then `colDif` would be 0 – 1 = -1 … `rowDif` would be 5 – 1 = 4. These would be the “magic” numbers we need to “add” to each cell in the selected cells collection to map to the proper cell to paste into.

Example: Inside the selected cells loop we need the new column and row index for each selected cell, in this case (from above) the first cell in the collection is “R3C3”, therefore its new column index would be its current index plus the `difCol` value. … 3 + (-1) = 2, same for the row… 3 + 4 = 7. This will paste cell “R3C3” into cell “R7C2”. An easy check is to look at “R1C1” and check the difference to “R3C3”… two columns right and two down. So, if we start at the paste cell “R5C0” then 5 + 2 = 7 and 0 + 2 = 2… I hope that makes sense.

The difference values from the top left selected cell rectangle from the pasted cell position can be used for all the selected cells and it should map properly without a lot of index juggling.

Finally, the code below. For the paste process a check is made for empty/null selection and returns. Then we get the “magic” difference values to add to each selected cell. A loop through the selected cells where the mapped row/column Indexes are created. A bounds check is made to ignore the cells out of the grid’s bounds, and a check for a new row. This will prevent pasting into the new row if it exists. If all conditions succeeded then paste the cell.

I added cell coloring for the “selected” and “pasted” cells in the code to visually help test this. I hope I got this right.

```
DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection copyCollection;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillGrid();
}

private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ClearCellColors();
  copyCollection = ws.SelectedCells;
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in copyCollection) {
    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
  }
}

private void btn_Paste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (copyCollection == null || copyCollection.Count == 0) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Copy button was not clicked - empty collection");
    return;
  }
  // get the difference between the top-left columns and rows
  int colDif = ws.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex - copyCollection.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(c => c.ColumnIndex).First().ColumnIndex;
  int rowDif = ws.CurrentCell.RowIndex - copyCollection.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(c => c.RowIndex).First().RowIndex;
  int rowIndex;
  int colIndex;
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in copyCollection) {
    rowIndex = cell.RowIndex + rowDif;
    colIndex = cell.ColumnIndex + colDif;
    if (rowIndex >= 0 && colIndex >= 0 &&
        rowIndex < ws.RowCount && colIndex < ws.ColumnCount &&
        !ws.Rows[rowIndex].IsNewRow) {
      ws.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value = cell.Value;
      ws.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
    else {
      Debug.WriteLine("Out of bounds: RowIndex:" + rowIndex + " ColIndex: " + colIndex);
    }
  }      
}

private void FillGrid() {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn newCol;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    newCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    newCol.Name = "Col " + i;
    ws.Columns.Add(newCol);
  }
  for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    int curRowIndex = ws.Rows.Add();
    for (int col = 0; col < ws.Columns.Count; col++) {
      ws.Rows[curRowIndex].Cells[col].Value = "R" + curRowIndex + "C" + col;
    }
  }
}

private void ClearCellColors() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ws.Rows) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
      cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Nice write up!  Just curious, since we are only looking for one minimum value in the copy source, is the OrderBy function more efficient than a foreach loop or essentially just an alternate syntax?

Comment: @Mike Paisner … I am not sure what you mean by _”only looking for one minimum value in the copy source”_ ? We would need two minimum values… the top most row and left most column unless I am missing something. The OrderBy in this case is just an alternate syntax, however, it is a more efficient approach depending on the collection. In this case however, it is irrelevant.